# HTML/CSS. Why field floating left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` with checkbox and button inside and wanna put field between them, but the field is always leftmost. I tried to use text instead of filed and that worked, but filed doesn't want to obey to my CSS rules.

[image]

Also, I need to position all of those using JavaScript.

```
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    var item = document.createElement("div");
    item.className="item";
    list.appendChild(item);
    var itemsField = document.createElement("input");
    itemsField.setAttribute('type', 'input');
    itemsField.className = '.itemsField';
    item.appendChild(itemsField);

    var taken = document.createElement("input");
...
    item.appendChild(taken);

...
    item.appendChild(del);
```

Some CSS rules:

```
.itemsField {
    display: inline-block;
    float:center;
    margin-left:1%;
}

checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no such rule as `float:center`. Where did you get that from? The keywords you can use are listed in documentation online, such as at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Values

Comment: `itemsField.className = '.itemsField';` is probably supposed to be `itemsField.className = 'itemsField';` You should also create a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Agreed with ADyson above. Also: `checkbox` isn't a selector for checkboxes. If you want to select all checkboxes, you'd use `input[type=checkbox]` as the selector. But it's not at all clear that's really want you want to do.

Comment: The simple answer is to add the field *after* the checkbox. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fq7jbm8e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why the css classes don't obey the rules is due to your script. So try changing

```
itemsField.className = '.itemsField';
```

to

```
itemsField.className = 'itemsField';
```

Besides, I don't think that there is a "center" value for the "float" property ...

```
.itemsField {
    display: inline-block;
    float:center;
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

If you want to center something, use `text-align : center` instead. Hope this help.

Comment: `text-align: center;` only centers text and not elements. Instead use `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`. This should set the item in center. If that isn't working it would be because of the other inherited attributes...

Comment: @SimonJensen `text-align: center` centers inline elements perfectly fine.

Comment: margin: 0 auto 0 auto / margin : 0 auto; most used for block elements ( such as p, div ... etc ) , usually inline elements use the text-align : center when it comes to centering

Answer (score 2):

You can use string literals. The other issue is the use of class name as `.itemsField`, you need to remove the dot. In your code you are appending the `div` with `innerText` `X` at the last

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

let innerDOM = `<div>
                 <input type = 'input' class ='itemsField'><span>X</span><input type ='checkbox' name ='taken'>
              </div>`;

list.innerHTML = innerDOM;
```

```css
.itemsField {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='list'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

float: center doesn't exist.
Above answers are pretty clear. 
But if you need a very simple answer, use this.

```
        <center>
     <input type="checkbox"> <input type="textarea"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
     </center>
```

if you want to move the whole thing into a specific position or style, use tag.

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete and has been for many years. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center So, the code in the question is using something that doesn't exist, and you suggest replacing it with something that is quite likely not to exist in the future.... :-s